# Dividing int by list and return values divided by

Tags: python, pycharm

So pretty much first set of code creating a list of primes from 2 - 10000000. i am trying to find the prime factorization for 25000001. so i want it to divide 25000001 by each number in the list and return that number to a list largest to smallest.

```
n = 10000000
primes = list()
multiples = set()
for i in range(2, n+1):
     if i not in multiples:
        primes.append(i)
        multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))

def primeFactors(x, factors):
    factorList = []
    if (x % factors) == 0:
        factorList.append(factors)
    print(factorList)

primeFactors(25000001, primes)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? (i.e., what doesn't work?)

Comment: it says the modulo isnt compatable with lists

Comment: factors is a list, you need to iterate over factors

Comment: What do you expect from `25000001 % [2,3,...]`?

Comment: What do you expect `x % factors` to do, exactly?

Comment: i want it to divide 25000001 by each number in the list and return that number to a factorList from largest to smallest.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to take a look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). If `factors` were a numpy array, instead of a normal Python list, `x % factors` would do exactly what you're hoping.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
factorList = [e for e in factors if x % e == 0]
```

The part

```
e for e in factors
```

will "iterate" over the elements of `factors`, and the condition `if x % e == 0` is used to *filter* the elements.

Comment: it is not printing the duplicate. for instance it prints out 13*5101*29. when it should be 13*13*29*5101

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check each number in factors against x, you need to iterate over

```
for n in factors: # iterate over the list
    if x % n == 0: # check "n" each number in the list
        factorList.append(n) # append n if the if statement is True
```

`[1,2,3,4...] % 3` is basically what you are currently doing, not checking each element.

You can achieve the same with a list comprehension:

`factorList = [n for n in factors if x % n == 0]`

Both the for loop and the list comprehension are equivalent.

To print it out in the format you want:

```
print "{} = {}".format(x," * ".join(map(str,factorList)))
```

If you just plan on printing the numbers, you can make them strings in the loop or list comprehension:

```
[str(x) for x in factors if n % x == 0]

print "{} = {}".format(x," * ".join(factorList))
```

To use `join` the elements need to be strings, so we would have to use the `str(x)` or use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert each `int` to string.

Comment: hey, do you know how to get the duplicates from the factor list. For example it prints out 13*5101*29. when it should be 13*13*29*5101

Comment: because you are only checking it once so you only append it once.

Comment: so to add the last number i would need to run it twice? but how if the function is in the list already?

Comment: I will add something tomorrow if you don't get an answer but you may be better asking another question.

Comment: @CorporalYouhouse: You should ask a new question. But try to solve it yourself first. Think about what it means for 13 to appear twice in the factor list. `25000001 % 13 == 0`, and it can't be any more `0` than `0`, right? But `25000001 % 169 == 0` _does_ tell you that there are at least 2 13s, and `25000001 % 2197 == 338` tells you that are aren't 3 13s. So, you want to append `13` twice, but no more. How do you automate that?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is actually doable, just not with lists. If you use a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array, you can throw it into arithmetic expressions, and it automatically broadcasts them over the whole array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> primes = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7, 11])
>>> 18 % primes
array([0, 0, 3, 4, 7])
>>> 18 % primes == 0
array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> primes[18 % primes == 0]
array([2, 3])
```

That's exactly what you were trying to do, almost exactly the way you were trying to do it—and it works exact as you'd expect it to.

This is obviously more concise, and it's almost always much more efficient; more importantly than either, it's often more readable.

---

What if you want to find repeated factors? Well, you can square the whole array, then cube it, and so on:

```
>>> primes[18 % (primes**2) == 0]
array([3])
>>> primes[18 % (primes**3) == 0]
array([])
```

Or, more efficiently, you can restrict the work to just the filtered-down array, and get the same results with a lot less work:

```
>>> factors = primes[18 % primes == 0]
>>> factors2 = factors[18 % (factors**2) == 0]
>>> factors2
array([3])
```